# Update field on related object

Tags: apex, trigger, invocable-method

:)

I want to update field on WorkOrderLineItem when the value on related product is changed (Product2). I don't have any error, but the field is not updated. Can you please take a look?

```
 @Invocablemethod
    public static void updateFieldOnWOLI(List<Product2> productsOnWoli){
  
  List<Asset> updateAS = new List<Asset>();
  List<Asset> prdAsPO = [Select Id,Product2Id from Asset where Product2Id = :productsOnWoli];
  
  List<WorkOrderLineItem> updateField = new List<WorkOrderLineItem>();
  List<WorkOrderLineItem> updateF = [
      Select Id, Work_Order_Status__c, UpdateField__c, status, AssetId 
      from WorkOrderLineItem 
      where status !='Completed' AND status != 'Canceled' 
           AND status != 'Cannot Complete' AND Work_Order_Status__c != 'Cannot Complete' 
           AND Work_Order_Status__c != 'Canceled' AND Work_Order_Status__c != 'Completed' 
           AND AssetId = :prdAsPO 
  ];
  for(WorkOrderLineItem uF : updateF ){
     uF.UpdateField__c= true;
     updateField.add(uF);
  }
  update updateField;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the **updateF** list ? Maybe there are no records matching your criteria or you made a mistake in the WHERE clause ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your query to look for the `LIST` of ids, rather than a specific id as you have in your query:

Change:

```
AND AssetId = :prdAsPO
```

To:

```
AND AssetId IN :prdAsPO
```